# what interactions would take place between a free proton and a dipolariton?

Tags: particle-physics, quasiparticles

What interactions can be expected to take place between a free proton and a [dipolariton](http://phys.org/news/2012-04-physicists-quantum-tunneling.html), (a) at high energies and (b) at lower energies?

A dipolariton is a bosonic quasi-particle mentioned in a [recent article](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/early/2012/04/05/science.1219010.abstract) in Science.  It is a static dipole that consists of an electron bound together with a photon.  I suspect the proton and dipolariton would be attracted to one another, but I'm unsure of the specifics.

Comment: Started a question on whether the assumptions in this question even make sense: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23859/can-a-dipolariton-exist-on-the-surface-of-a-metal.

Comment: I suspect the most likely outcome of a proton encountering a dipolariton would be disruption of he dipolariton through formation of a hydrogen atom. Quasiparticles in general are quite delicate compared to fundamental particles, and the proton is just too heavy to participate easily in the dipolariton without breaking it. One qualifier: Very cold protons might be compatible. (Er... I'm going to dare a guess: Are you by any chance wondering if a dipolariton-driven proton might provide a "cold fusion" mechanism? If so, I would say no due to the disruption I just described. All quasi's are weak.)

Comment: @TerryBollinger, it's a long shot, but I was curious whether neutron formation was a possibility, since the quasiparticle is bosonic.

Comment: It's an interesting question, since some quantum values do match. The big inhibitor against neutron formation is always the weak interaction, which is powerfully inhibited by the huge mass of the [*W* boson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons). You can encourage weak interactions somewhat by adding excess protons to a nucleus, so that the electrostatic repulsion stress is released by p-to-n conversion. That encourages [electron capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture). The energies are huge compared to quasiparticle levels, however, and even then capture can take days.

Comment: @TerryBollinger I'm not too familiar with the restrictions arising from the weak interaction -- I assume that implies that you would need a significant amount of energy?  I was imagining a proton whose movement is restricted within the lattice of a metal and a photon that is at X-ray or gamma energies.

Comment: If you invoke gammas, hot fusion is possible, but any quasiparticles become irrelevant due to their vastly lower binding energies. Picture cannonballs (gammas) flying through spiderwebs (quasiparticles). Also, fusion is more than just having lots of energy, else the entire super-hot core of the sun would have exploded a very long time ago. The weak force protects us from that by making it very, very hard to convert a proton into a neutron. Fusion energy levels pale by comparison. One way or the other, proton-to-neutron conversions require one of those *W* bosons (please see my earlier refs).

Comment: @TerryBollinger thank you for the informative explanation. That's very helpful for thinking about the relative magnitudes of the forces involved.  One more question -- the binding energies of quasiparticles, I assume these do not ever scale up with the energies of the constituent particles?  E.g., what is a spiderweb in one context could not become something quite different when you have a gamma resonating within a cavity at the surface of a metal?

Comment: Describe how to resonate a fired cannonball between two spiderwebs and you will have your answer.