# In what environments can a dipolariton form?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, quasiparticles

In what environments can a [dipolariton](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/early/2012/04/05/science.1219010.abstract) form?  The article in *Science* in which it is introduced discusses it in the context of an optical cavity in a semiconductor.  Can this quasiparticle occur elsewhere — as a free particle or on the surface or in the bulk of a metal, for example?

A dipolariton is a bosonic quasiparticle that consists of two excitons, one an electron together with a hole, the other an electron together with a photon.  I'm asking this question to get a sense of whether a [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23640/what-interactions-would-take-place-between-a-free-proton-and-a-dipolariton) that was raised not too long ago makes sense.

**EDIT:** To be concrete, could a dipolariton form in the context of the system explored in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.5773v1.pdf)?

Comment: Good question! Unfortunately I know nothing about dipolaritons, but if I find anyone who does, I'll definitely try to send them here.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky definitely, please do.  Also, could you take a look at the linked question and see if you know of anyone that might be able to address it?